# STSADM.exe - "Operation completed successfully" - Twice?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-deployment

For a command such as this:

```
C:\>stsadm -o upgradeSolution -name zzz.wsp -filename zzz.wsp -allowGacDeployment -local
```

I receive two outputs of the success statement rather than just one:

```
Operation completed successfully.

Operation completed successfully.
```

It seems to be related to the `-local` flag, so my guess would be that it successfully creates the **Timer Job** then runs execadmsvcjobs under the hood.

```
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Thoughts on this?

Comment: TechNet states that running `upgradesolution` with `-local` does not use the timer service and the job is run synchronously: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262014.aspx

Comment: That makes sense, but what is the second operation that completes successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is nearly as exciting as it seems...

Within STSADM, if you deploy a local solution (immediate), the following happens (crack open Reflector):

```
    base.DeployRetractSolution(solution, urls, userTypedIn, lcid, gacInstallWPPackDlls, true, force);
    base.OutputSucceedMessage();
```

However, if you deploy a solution across the farm (timer job), this happens:

```
base.CreateSolnDeployTimerJob(strTime, immediate, solution, urls, userTypedIn, SPSolutionDeploymentJobType.Deploy, lcid, gacInstallWPPackDlls, force);
```

**base.OutputSucceedMessage();** just writes the localized language version of "Operation Completed Successfully" to the console.

Both of these do things under the hood that generate a STSADM SPOperation (and a "Operation Completed Successfully" console message), but the immediate one just has another **base.OutputSucceedMessage();** on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use upgradesolution with care, since it does not support adding new features to a solution package.

Also be warned that if you use -local you only deploy on your local WFE. For consistency i always use -immediate and after i have finished adding timer jobs i run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs

Im not sure about the two messages, but since upgradesolution is a two stage operation that first adds the new version of the old solution and then adds it, it would make sense that this was why you got two messages.

Comment: That makes sense, and thanks for the recommendations.  This is for deploying locally to a single WFE - so running with -local to do the upgrade synchronously is ideal.